# Issue with single quotes while executing stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure. Please check below the procedure description. If I pass @PayerName = '2342342', the stored procedure is throwing error Incorrect syntax near '2342342'

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetPayer(@PayerName VARCHAR(50) = '')
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON
 --
 DECLARE @Qry NVARCHAR(MAX)
 --
 SET @Qry = 'SELECT CM.CODE AS PAYER_CODE,
                       CM.NAME AS PAYER_NAME,
                       CM.ADDR_1 AS ADDRESS,                            
                  FROM CUST_MASTER CM    
                  WHERE CM.ISDELETED = ''N'' ' 
 IF(@PayerName IS NOT NULL AND @PayerName <> '' )
  SET @Qry = @Qry + 'AND (CM.NAME LIKE ''%' + @PayerName + '%'' OR CM.CODE LIKE ''%' + @PayerName + '%'')'
 --  
 EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL  @Qry
 --  
END
```

Comment: Use parameterized queries instead of dynamic SQL. This isn't a single quote issue, this is a SQL injection vulnerability. No amount of quoting is going to fix this.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You can actually use both together and this is a good example why. The `SET` line should say `SET @Qry = @Qry + 'AND (CM.NAME LIKE ''%'' + @PayerName + ''%'' OR CM.CODE LIKE ''%'' + @PayerName + ''%'')', then you need to pass through the parameter to `sp_executesql`

Comment: Why would you inject the value though, @Charlieface, when you can parametrise it; which is by far safer.

Comment: @Charlieface only if *no* user input is included in the query string. The query still needs to be a parameterized query.

Comment: I personally, however, don't see why this is really a dynamic query; seems like the required logic could be obtained with an `OR`, and (if needed) you can add an `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to stop the caching of the wrong query plan.

Comment: There's no reason to use dynamic SQL in this case at all. Not even an `OR` clause. `IF` can be used to execute two different queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been mentioned in the comments, there is no need for dynamic SQL here. There are 2 non-dynamic options you can go for here; for what you have there's unlikely to be much of a performance difference if any. Personally I tend to use an `OR`, however, (as Panagiotis Kanavos mentions in the comments) you can also use `IF` logic.

#### `OR` Logic (with `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`)

```sql
CREATE PROC dbo.GetPayer @PayerName varchar(50) = NULL AS --You're better off using NULL here in my opinion
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT CM.CODE AS PAYER_CODE,
           CM.NAME AS PAYER_NAME,
           CM.ADDR_1 AS ADDRESS,                            
      FROM CUST_MASTER CM    
      WHERE CM.ISDELETED = 'N'
        AND ((CM.NAME LIKE '%' + @PayerName + '%' OR CM.CODE LIKE '%' + @PayerName + '%')
         OR  @PayerName IS NULL)
      OPTION (RECOMPILE);

END;
GO
```

#### `IF` logic

```sql
CREATE PROC dbo.GetPayer @PayerName varchar(50) = NULL AS --You're better off using NULL here in my opinion
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF @PayerName IS NULL
        SELECT CM.CODE AS PAYER_CODE,
               CM.NAME AS PAYER_NAME,
               CM.ADDR_1 AS ADDRESS,                            
          FROM CUST_MASTER CM    
          WHERE CM.ISDELETED = 'N';
    ELSE
        SELECT CM.CODE AS PAYER_CODE,
               CM.NAME AS PAYER_NAME,
               CM.ADDR_1 AS ADDRESS,                            
          FROM CUST_MASTER CM    
          WHERE CM.ISDELETED = 'N'
            AND (CM.NAME LIKE '%' + @PayerName + '%' OR CM.CODE LIKE '%' + @PayerName + '%');

END;
GO
```

If you "must" use dynamic SQL, then you need to properly parametrise the query, not inject the parameter:

#### Parametrised Dynamic Query

```sql
CREATE PROC dbo.GetPayer @PayerName varchar(50) = NULL AS --You're better off using NULL here in my opinion
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
            @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);
    SET @SQL = N'SELECT CM.CODE AS PAYER_CODE,' + @CRLF +
               N'     CM.NAME AS PAYER_NAME,' + @CRLF +
               N'     CM.ADDR_1 AS ADDRESS,' + @CRLF +                
               N'FROM CUST_MASTER CM' + @CRLF +
               N'WHERE CM.ISDELETED = ''N''' +
               CASE WHEN @PayerName IS NOT NULL THEN @CRLF + N'  AND (CM.NAME LIKE ''%'' + @PayerName + ''%'' OR CM.CODE LIKE ''%'' + @PayerName + ''%'');' ELSE N';' END;

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@PayerName varchar(50)', @PayerName;

END;
GO
```

Comment: `OR` will screw up indexing. `IF` is much better, and can be also be combined into one query with `UNION ALL`, but still subject to parameter sniffing.

Comment: @Charlieface the `OR` messing it up won't matter, there's a leading wild card in there. for a simple query like this, SQL Server is "generally" clever enough about the `OR` when `NULL` is passed for the parameter.

Comment: Good point, missed that. Re index union, on simple queries like this: yes probably, but I've seen many a complex query plan go awry.

Comment: Oh, complex ones definately go awry, @Charlieface . For those I do prefer to use a dynamic query, and add the clauses the query needs. (You *can* use `IF` logic, but  end up with *n*! different queries to maintain, which gets out of hand very quickly. >_< )

Comment: Exactly why I wanted to stick to dynamic. See @AaronBertrand: [#BackToBasics: An Updated Kitchen Sink Example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example)

Comment: I link to that one quite often, @Charlieface . Gail's articles are also, however, well worth a read: [Catch-all queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) & [Revisiting catch-all queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the dynamic query at all. Not able to figure out the issue but you can simply use the following query:

```
SELECT CM.CODE AS PAYER_CODE,
       CM.NAME AS PAYER_NAME,
       CM.ADDR_1 AS ADDRESS,                            
  FROM CUST_MASTER CM    
 WHERE CM.ISDELETED = 'N'
   AND (CM.NAME LIKE '%' + @PayerName + '%' 
        OR CM.CODE LIKE '%' + @PayerName + '%'
        OR  @PayerName IS NULL)
```